# Change Internet Explorer Window Title

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser

I'm developing a toolbar for IE in C#. What I want to do is I would like to change the title of internet explorer to something I decide, when this toolbar is made visible in IE. I can add a status text by using WebBrowserClass status text but I found no way to make change to title. Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer... Use SetWindowText Function.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that HTML page tells the browser window title info. So may be change the html page which browser is loading. This may be a crude solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response zenwalker. Actually what I wanted was to do the title upon visibility of toolbar instead of having to depend on page. Anyway I did have the answer in front of me just did it wrongly. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176497) describes how to do so. I edited the wrong key.

Comment: @arunondeck, you need to add that as an answer rather than just mentioning it in a comment.

Comment: @arun,
The link talks about altering the registry key. I dont think thats good way to solve the problem. Playing with registry isnt as easy as you think.

Comment: @zenwalker, yes you're right. And it doesnt walk as I thought it would. Actually I would prefer something which doesn't involve the registry. Is there any other method?

Comment: Well since the browser is a low level application, i guess you need to look at the developer forum of IE.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the registry.

[Read this article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176497)

The title is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` as **Window Title**

Comment: the question is, is it a good idea to play with registry? Many experts suggests its not good and some times registry gets corrupted and dont suggest it to be played with unless its an system application. Plus this change is a parmanent right? What if that add on to the browser is removed.

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray : I did that only. But it wouldn't change the title when the toolbar is made visible. You would have to restart IE in order for the change to be visible. I would like to be able to have something such that as soon as the toolbar is made visible, the title changes.

Comment: I don't think the title can be changed on the fly.